# I can't position a div in CSS without it messing up the animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I tried making a rotating square that would turn into an oval while rotating 180 degrees, the issue I encountered is that as the square rotates it moves to the left so that the top-left corner always stays in the same. [Visualization of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYgsb.png). I think it's caused by the fact that my animation changes the width of the square:

```
`@keyframes squarestuff {
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    width: 5rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this

```
@keyframes squarestuff {
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    width: 5rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform-origin:center center;
  }
```

Since it transform the center and rotate about new center.
make the width of div contain the square as width of square if still there is problem

Comment: Please  click the 'tic' to verify the answer is correct.. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

This is it:
https://jsfiddle.net/0pz1tv7q/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  animation: mymove 5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes mymove {
    100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    width: 25%;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Square CSS</h2>
<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the center of the oval to remain in the center of the 'square' (i.e not to move) then you can use a transform scale instead of changing the width.

This snippet rotates the square with its center always in the same place and adds the oval as a pseudo element so you see what is happening and that the center does not move:

```css
div {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: magenta;
  animation: squarestuff 5s linear infinite;
  transform-origin: center center;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes squarestuff {
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1, 1);
  background: blue;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  animation: square2oval 5s linear infinite;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes square2oval {
  50% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.5, 1);
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```